# Python Requests Get XML

Tags: python, xml, python-requests

If I go to http://boxinsider.cratejoy.com/feed/ I can see the XML just fine. But when I try to access it using python requests, I get a 403 error.

```
    blog_url = 'http://boxinsider.cratejoy.com/feed/'
    headers = {'Accepts': 'text/html,application/xml'}
    blog_request = requests.get(blog_url, timeout=10, headers=headers)
```

Any ideas on why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's hosted by WPEngine and they filter user agents.

Try this:

```
USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36"

requests.get('http://boxinsider.cratejoy.com/feed/', headers={'User-agent': USER_AGENT})
```